# List of max values in a sequence?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first question in stackoverflow, I'm looking for this solution for days and it is very frustrating.

Imagine, I have a sequence every 2 seconds...

```
sequence--> {55361500: 262.6, 55372250: 81.5, 55422280: 9.5}
sequence--> {55361500: 284.48, 55372250: 90.0, 55422280: 12.2}
sequence--> {55361500: 284.47, 55372250: 88.5, 55422280: 8.1}
sequence--> {55361500: 262.59, 55372250: 95.5, 55422280: 6.7}
sequence--> {55361500: 249.32, 55372250: 81.5, 55422280: 5.5}
```

I would like to have a list of max values, I mean when a sequence number decrease, the number of the maximum value is stored in that list. For example:

```
sequence--> {55361500: 262.6, 55372250: 81.5, 55422280: 9.5}
lst_max_seq = [262.6, 81.5, 9.5]

sequence--> {55361500: 284.48, 55372250: 90.0, 55422280: 12.2}
lst_max_seq = [284.48, 90.0, 12.2]

sequence--> {55361500: 284.47, 55372250: 88.5, 55422280: 8.1}
lst_max_seq = [284.48, 90.0, 12.2]

sequence--> {55361500: 262.59, 55372250: 95.5, 55422280: 6.7}
lst_max_seq = [284.48, 95.5, 12.2]

sequence--> {55361500: 249.32, 55372250: 81.5, 55422280: 5.5}
lst_max_seq = [284.48, 95.5, 12.2]
```

When I run my code, the values of lst_max_seq are the same than the values of the sequence.
Any tips?

```
while True:
    >>code to get sequence<<

    for key in dt_seq:
        if len(lista_max_seq) < len(dt_seq):
            lista_max_seq.append(dt_seq[key])

    for k, elem in enumerate(lista_max_seq):
        if elem > lista_def_max[k]:
            lista_def_max[k] = elem

    time.sleep(2)
```

If you have questions, you will have 100%, just ask me I will answer fast. Thank you =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your `lista_max_seq` at the beginning of each iteration:

```py
while True:
    ...
    lista_max_seq = []
```

Otherwise after the first iteration, your programm never passes `len(lista_max_seq) < len(dt_seq)` check.

You do not need your first `for` loop: you can retrieve dict values using `dict.values()`: `list_of_values = list(sequence.values())`.

```py
stored_max_values = [0, 0, 0] # initialize your list
# if you know sequence's length, you can do:
# stored_max_values = [0] * length

while True:
    ... # code to get sequence

    new_values = list(sequence.values()) # replaces your first loop

    for i, (new_val, stored_val) in enumerate(zip(new_values, stored_max_values)): 
        if new_val > stored_val:
            stored_max_values[i] = new_val


    time.sleep(2)
```

This example uses [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

**If you want to keep labels**, you can store values in another dict. Initialize it with your first sequence, then iterate over the new values and replace in the stored dict the higher values.

You can iterate over `dict.items()` to get both keys and values.

```py
stored_max_values = first_sequence # <- a dict
# if you can't get first sequence here, you could do:
# stored_max_values = {k: 0 for k in labels}
# where labels are a list of labels
# this would give {55361500: 0, 55372250: 0, 55422280: 0} here 

while True:
    ... # code to get sequence as new_sequence

    for k, v in new_sequence.items():
        if v > stored_max_values[k]:
            stored_max_values[k] = v

    time.sleep(2)
```

`stored_max_values` is then a dict containing (label, max value) pairs.
This second example use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#examples).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The numeric values ​​of  55XXXXXX are labels and they must remain "connected" to the values ​​in the stored_max_values list. When a value falls a certain percentage of the maximum corresponding to a 55XXXXXX label, I would like to display the label and the final value on the screen. Maybe I'm wrong doing it with lists, I don't know. And I don't know to explain it better, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. If labels are guaranteed to stay the same, you can store values in a dictionary containing the same labels as keys and the max values as values. I'll edit my anwser.

Comment: Thank you for your time! The problem was I had to create a stored_max_values outside of the while True loop. Im doing two while True loops nested. The first one get the stored_max_values with zeros and the nested second one makes the operations. Thanks for your help!